# cannot connect on SQLserver with Docker on mac

Tags: sql-server, linux, macos, docker

I'm trying to setup SQLserver on my mac using Docker. 
When I start it, it seems to be working, but when I try to connect with mssql, it crashes. 
I have tried with localhost instead of 0.0.0.0, same result.

```
iMac benoitd$ **docker run** -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=DB22017' -p 
1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux

ee2f1a94410dfb6e5f39ba009ffee20b906270e9602d831ff2344e93d2ec5d14

iMac benoitd$ **docker ps**

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ee2f1a94410d        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/mssq"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   awesome_mahavira

iMac benoitd$ **mssql -s 0.0.0.0:1433 -u sa -p 'DB22017'**

Connecting to 0.0.0.0:1433...
Error: Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0:1433:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 0.0.0.0:1433 0.0.0.0:1433:1433

iMac benoitd$ **docker ps**

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: I'd guess that you do not need to provide a port with your `-s` parameter, for example: `mssql -s 0.0.0.0 -u sa -p 'DB22017'`, but I haven't used mssql yet...

Comment: tried it. no success. The weird thing is that the sqlserver process dies when I try to connect.

Comment: Did you check the logs? When I try to run your docker run command it crashes after a few seconds with this error message - `Configuring Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)...
Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) setup failed with error code 1. Please check the setup log in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
`

Comment: I don't see /var/opt. I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Not on your mac, in the container. Start the mssql server without `-d` command. It then runs in the normal mode and not in daemon mode. You see all the logs on your console.

Comment: Assuming you are using `sql-cli`, the `-s` option requires host name or IP _only_; to specify port you need the `-o` option.

Comment: ok, some progress... I ran docker with -d (I'm new to docker), and got this error:
Configuring Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)...
Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) setup failed with error code 1. Please check the setup log in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.

Comment: how do I get the log file from inside the container ?

Answer (score 4):

d'oh.... the problem was with the password for sql server. It need to be a strong pw.

thanks for your help! and happy new year :)